# How would you design Monopoly?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monopoly game in OOD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576271/monopoly-game-in-ood)

I got asked this question in an interview the other day. Obviously it's very broad and there's no way you're going to cover everything in the short amount of time you have. I'm not sure I did a good job of answering the question however. What sort of things are the most important to mention?

In the version of the question I was asked, assume there are 4 players who are participating remotely, and a simplified version of the game - players can roll, they can buy property, and they can pay rent to other players.

Comment: That covers the object aspects of the problem - I think this is more of a webapp structure question.

Answer (score 1):

They were most likely looking for your understanding of objects and linking those objects.  Perhaps even entries in a database and links between them (players, and properties, and the properties linked to the objects).

Answer (score 1):

I think the key word in the question is "remotely" So I think they were after how the players would interact with each other and the server?

Items to cover in your answer could include:

- Is it a desktop or web based application
- How do users communicate to each other  peer - peer or via a central server
- How does one user know when another use has performed an action, does each user poll the server? Or does the server push messages to the user?
- What technology stack would you use? JMS, WFC, Applet, JavaScript? etc
- What load does the server need to handle how scalable do you need to make your solution. Having 100 users poll the server every 2 seconds may be fine, but not probably ideal for one million users.
- Do you need a message queue/bus
- etc

However if the question was about programming in general I guess you would talk about inheritance and objects, Interfaces, database design etc.